# How to print variable value using awk? (code prints variable name instead)

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

Please bear with me as I'm new to writing shell scripts.

Input

Metadata

Column 1 
A01 
A02  A03

Column 2 
A_1
A_2
A_3 
...

FILENAME (example of current format)
(2 columns names Well and Area)

Met-test8A-DBMCK_A01_w1D27B99D4-0BA0-4AA0-B10A-04558144C3BE 62577.5

Met-test8A-DBMCK_A01_w1D27B99D4-0BA0-4AA0-B10A-04558144C3BE 62688.4

Met-test8A-DBMCK_A01_w1D27B99D4-0BA0-4AA0-B10A-04558144C3BE 62733.3

Met-test8A-DBMCK_A02_w192E97024-E632-4D00-A525-A4204DEF9ECE 62263.3

Met-test8A-DBMCK_A02_w192E97024-E632-4D00-A525-A4204DEF9ECE 59554

Met-test8A-DBMCK_A02_w192E97024-E632-4D00-A525-A4204DEF9ECE 54602.8

Met-test8A-DBMCK_A02_w192E97024-E632-4D00-A525-A4204DEF9ECE 528.125

Met-test8A-DBMCK_A02_w192E97024-E632-4D00-A525-A4204DEF9ECE 62751.8

Met-test8A-DBMCK_A02_w192E97024-E632-4D00-A525-A4204DEF9ECE 56752.3

Met-test8A-DBMCK_A02_w192E97024-E632-4D00-A525-A4204DEF9ECE 51428.8

Met-test8A-DBMCK_A02_w192E97024-E632-4D00-A525-A4204DEF9ECE 65778

Met-test8A-DBMCK_A02_w192E97024-E632-4D00-A525-A4204DEF9ECE 533.406

Met-test8A-DBMCK_A03_w175F73215-12C2-4E07-8894-795CB8F31A4D 3839.47

Met-test8A-DBMCK_A03_w175F73215-12C2-4E07-8894-795CB8F31A4D 8801.2

Met-test8A-DBMCK_A03_w175F73215-12C2-4E07-8894-795CB8F31A4D 35468.9

Met-test8A-DBMCK_A03_w175F73215-12C2-4E07-8894-795CB8F31A4D 528.125

Goal is to grep for line that contains string from first column in metadata (e.g. A01) and add a new column at the end of the row with string from the second column (e.g. A_1)

Those lines containing A02, get a new column with A_2
Those lines containing A03, get a new column with A_3, etc

I have this script, which does most of the job:

```
#!/bin/bash -l

pop=$1 ### Metadata file 

n=$(wc -l ${pop} | awk '{print $1}')

x=1
while [ $x -le $n ] 
do

        string="sed -n ${x}p ${pop}"
        str=$($string)

                var=$(echo $str | awk '{print $1, $2}')
                set -- $var
               c1=$1   ### e.g. A01 ###
               c2=$2   ### e.g. A_1 ###


                grep ${c1} FILENAME | xargs -d "\n" -rI % echo '% $c2' > ${c1}.data

        x=$(( $x + 1 ))

done
```

The current output gives:

Met-test8A-DBMCK_A01_w1D27B99D4-0BA0-4AA0-B10A-04558144C3BE     62577.5 $c2

Met-test8A-DBMCK_A01_w1D27B99D4-0BA0-4AA0-B10A-04558144C3BE     62688.4 $c2

Met-test8A-DBMCK_A01_w1D27B99D4-0BA0-4AA0-B10A-04558144C3BE     62733.3 $c2

Met-test8A-DBMCK_A01_w1D27B99D4-0BA0-4AA0-B10A-04558144C3BE     59593.6 $c2

Met-test8A-DBMCK_A01_w1D27B99D4-0BA0-4AA0-B10A-04558144C3BE     66253.3 $c2

Met-test8A-DBMCK_A01_w1D27B99D4-0BA0-4AA0-B10A-04558144C3BE     59276.8 $c2

The issue being that this prints $c2 at the end instead of A_1.

So, desired output would be:

Met-test8A-DBMCK_A01_w1D27B99D4-0BA0-4AA0-B10A-04558144C3BE     62577.5 A_1

Met-test8A-DBMCK_A01_w1D27B99D4-0BA0-4AA0-B10A-04558144C3BE     62688.4 A_1

Met-test8A-DBMCK_A01_w1D27B99D4-0BA0-4AA0-B10A-04558144C3BE     62733.3 A_1

Met-test8A-DBMCK_A01_w1D27B99D4-0BA0-4AA0-B10A-04558144C3BE     59593.6 A_1

I think I'm just using the incorrect syntax at echo '% $c2', but variants such as ${c2} or $2 only have the same issue. I've looked online but unsure of how to ask for the correct syntax at the moment. Not possible to do manually as this file has thousands of rows.

Would really appreciate any help

Thanks

L

Comment: Your approach is wrong - see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for some, but not all of the issues with your script. Please do as @Cyrus suggested if you'd like help doing whatever it is you're trying to do the right way.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> grep ${c1} FILENAME | xargs -d "\n" -rI % echo '% $c2' > ${c1}.data
> ```
>
> The issue being that this prints $c2 at the end instead of A_1.

You need to use double quotes to expand the variable, like `echo "% $c2"`

Comment: Thanks so much, sadly I knew it was a simple fix, but frustrated as I had absolutely no idea what it was

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear but is this all you're trying to do?

```
$ cat file
Met-test8A-DBMCK_A01_w1D27B99D4-0BA0-4AA0-B10A-04558144C3BE 62733.3
Met-test8A-DBMCK_A02_w192E97024-E632-4D00-A525-A4204DEF9ECE 62263.3
Met-test8A-DBMCK_A03_w175F73215-12C2-4E07-8894-795CB8F31A4D 3839.47

$ awk -F'_' '{print $0, gensub(/0/,"_",1,$2)}' file
Met-test8A-DBMCK_A01_w1D27B99D4-0BA0-4AA0-B10A-04558144C3BE 62733.3 A_1
Met-test8A-DBMCK_A02_w192E97024-E632-4D00-A525-A4204DEF9ECE 62263.3 A_2
Met-test8A-DBMCK_A03_w175F73215-12C2-4E07-8894-795CB8F31A4D 3839.47 A_3
```

The above uses GNU awk for gensub() but with any awk:

```
$ awk -F'_' '{new=$2; sub(/0/,"_",new); print $0, new}' file
Met-test8A-DBMCK_A01_w1D27B99D4-0BA0-4AA0-B10A-04558144C3BE 62733.3 A_1
Met-test8A-DBMCK_A02_w192E97024-E632-4D00-A525-A4204DEF9ECE 62263.3 A_2
Met-test8A-DBMCK_A03_w175F73215-12C2-4E07-8894-795CB8F31A4D 3839.47 A_3
```

Or maybe you need that "meta" file to provide the mapping to something that's not as straight-forward and calculable as A02 -> A_2 and then it'd be this, again with any awk:

```
$ cat meta
A01 whatever
A02 other_stuff
A03 somethin

$ awk 'NR==FNR{map[$1]=$2;next} {print $0, map[$2]}' meta FS='_' file
Met-test8A-DBMCK_A01_w1D27B99D4-0BA0-4AA0-B10A-04558144C3BE 62733.3 whatever
Met-test8A-DBMCK_A02_w192E97024-E632-4D00-A525-A4204DEF9ECE 62263.3 other_stuff
Met-test8A-DBMCK_A03_w175F73215-12C2-4E07-8894-795CB8F31A4D 3839.47 somethin
```

If it's none of that then do tell us what it is you're trying to do so we can help you do it the right way rather than putting a bandaid on doing it the wrong way.

Comment: Hi thanks for the input, Grisha Levit above answered just fine. But you're very right in showing there's a much more efficient way of doing this. The meta file was the only way I was familiar with. I'll keep this in mind and will try to make my questions more clear in the future. Thanks again

Comment: "just fine" is relative :-). Your original script has several problems, not just efficiency, so getting that part of it to produce the output you expect given the input you provided is not all that useful (it will produce unexpected output given different input). You said you're just beginning to learn shell programming so just learn to do things the right way rather than limping along hoping for the best doing things the wrong way. It's not like there's any benefit whatsoever to doing it the wrong way.

Comment: Understood. Thanks again